# xpath changed when clicking on an element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on an automation testing tool. For finding an element xpath, I have written code which is working fine for almost all elements. But the same code does not work for few elements and found that element's parent node is null. I have taken xpath helper of chrome and found xpath of a span element as below.

> /html[@class='ng-scope']/body/div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[@class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all']/a[@class='ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover']/span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w']

after clicking on the same element, the incomplete xpath was returned as below

> /div[@class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all']/a[@class='ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover']/span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w xh-highlight']

even from xpath helper of chrome does not returning complete path. How to fix this issue or is there anything I am missing?

xpath helper that I have used is only to show the change in path after clicking on element. Actually I am using below code from internet to get the xpath after clicking on element.

```
function(element) {
            var ix = 0;
            var siblings = element.parentNode.childNodes; // getting error parent node is null
            for (var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) {
                var sibling = siblings[i];
                if (sibling === element) {
                    return  getPathTo(element.parentNode) + '/' + element.tagName + '[' + (ix + 1) + ']';
                }
                if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling.tagName === element.tagName)
                    ix++;
            }
        }
```

as I am getting error, the complete xpath was not returned from the function. Is the above code is

Comment: Your question has weak context. First of all show your code, which technology your using ?, Secondly, what happens on the click ? i.e. for example class is added or what is the functionality needs to be performed. Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, I have modified my question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the XPATH details you have provided

Before clicking:

```
/html[@class='ng-scope']
    /body
        /div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']
            /div[@class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all']
                /a[@class='ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover']
                    /span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w']
```

After clicking

```
/div[@class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all']
                /a[@class='ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover']
                    /span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w xh-highlight']
```

After clicking the element only 'xh-highlight' has been added with the Span i.e. that element got highlighted.

Here, you can customized this XPATH like, which should work perfectly, e.g.

```
/div[@class='ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all']
                    /a[@class='ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all ui-state-hover ui-datepicker-prev-hover']
                        /span[contains(@class,'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w')]
```

i.e. instead of '=', use 'contains()' method in Span.

But I would recommend, instead of using XPath helper create your own XPath locators

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have modified the question. I am using javascript function to get the xpath. But getting the error as the parent node is null.